# angular 2 routing to different page

Tags: angular

i have been trying to navigate to different pages using angular 2. it navigates but the content of the previous page also gets displayed. Please help me out.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rb25.png)

In the image, when i click on sign up button, i get the text register, but i want the buttons to go and only the text "register" to appear.

app.component.html-

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
<button type=button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="onClick1();">Sign In</button>
<button type=button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" (click)="onClick2();">Sign Up</button>
</div>
<div class="outer-outlet">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>

app.routes.ts-

import { Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { SignInComponent } from './SignIn/signin.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './SignUp/signup.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'signUp', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'signIn', component: SignInComponent },
{ path: 'signUp', component: SignUpComponent }];
```

main.ts-

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { SignInComponent } from './SignIn/signin.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './SignUp/signup.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
declarations: [ AppComponent, SignInComponent, SignUpComponent],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
class AppModule {}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are on your application shell, so they will always appear.

If you don't want them to appear on every route, then move the buttons to their own route.

For example:
app.routes.ts would contain ONLY the router-outlet (no buttons)

Routes would be:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'signIn', component: SignInComponent },
  { path: 'signUp', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
];
```

The welcome component would contain the buttons.